# GitHub Actions parallel but with one job depending on success

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am struggling this GitHub Action logic. Currently there are two matrix jobs:
tests and build. build depends on tests. both work parallel for web and API.
this currently works, but takes forever because they depend on each other.

What I want to achieve is that they both run in parallel, but only deploy (last step in job: build, - name: Deploy image) if tests are successful.

This is the current action script (I deleted some linename: deploy

```
jobs:
  tests:
    name: run tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres

    strategy:
      matrix:
        org: [web, api] #Array of org mnemonics to use below
        include:
          - org: web
            appname: web
          - org: api
            appname: api
    steps:
      - name: run tests
        env:
          TEST_DATABASE_URL: "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
        run: yarn rw test ${{ matrix.appname }} --no-watch

  build:
    name: build-and-push-image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: tests
    strategy:
      matrix:
        org: [web, api] #Array of org mnemonics to use below
        include:
          - org: web
            dockerfile: ./web/Dockerfile
            appname: web
            apptokensecret: DEVWEB_APP_TOKEN
            image: dockerregistry.xyz/ffy/FFYBuildFormWeb
          - org: api
            dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
            appname: api
            apptokensecret: DEVAPI_APP_TOKEN
            image: dockerregistry.xyz/ffy/FFYBuildFormApi
    steps:
      # here we login to container registry
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_DOMAIN }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      # get Tag names as identifier for registry Push
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ matrix.image }}

        # here we build and push to container registry
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          file: ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - name: Deploy image
        uses: floms/action-caprover@v1
        with:
          host: "${{ secrets.CAPROVER_SERVER }}"
          password: "${{ secrets.CAPROVER_PASSWORD }}"
          app: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}${{ matrix.appname }}
          image: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
```

The idea would be to introduce a third job which deploys the image, when both jobs (test & build) finished successfully.

The problem I have is: how do i get the data from job "build" to a third one to deploy it? so this should be in a separate job I guess:

```
  - name: Deploy image
    uses: floms/action-caprover@v1
    with:
      host: "${{ secrets.CAPROVER_SERVER }}"
      password: "${{ secrets.CAPROVER_PASSWORD }}"
      app: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}${{ matrix.appname }}
      image: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
jobs:
  ...
  deploy:
     needs: [build, test]
```

Since test also has `needs: build`, the sequence of execution will be build, test, deploy. The build job can define outputs and upload build artifacts that you can access from the deploy job as well.

As an alternative you can pass data from one job to the next:

```
jobs:
  build:
     ...
  test:
     needs: [build]
     ...
  deploy:
     needs: [test]
```

And then in your deploy job request the artefacts published in the build job. [Unfortunately you can't really](https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/2477) use [output variables this way](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17245).

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, but its not quite what i meant: job: test and job: build are indeed supposed to run independently to save time. but job: deploy should only run if job: test is successfull. and here is the question again -> how do i get the variables from job: build to job: deploy?

Comment: The default is that a job will only run if all it's `needs` are successful. So if you define these on the job, deploy will only run if the build and test jobs succeed.

Comment: You can't pass any variables out of a matrix job. But the deploy job can download the artefacts that were attached to the workflow run. So in your build job add a `actions/upload-artifact` action and in your deploy job download the contents again using the `actions/download-artifact`. If yo need to pass any variables you'll need to store them on disk and then upload them as an artifact.

Comment: Hi, thanks! i did just look into the artifacts thing. its kinda complicated ;) but it works!
the main goal was to speed up the process by testing and building in parallel. and only deplyoing on a successfull test...

Comment: Do you only want to deploy anything if all tests pass? Or is the tests of a single element pass, it can be deployed? Cause in that case you might want to make a single workflow with matrix strategy that calls a single callable workflow with different parameters each time parameters. The callable workflow then does build, test, deploy for a single piece.